# Home page seller products are displaying above slideshow container

Tags: magento-1.9, php, html

I have installed SUPEE-6788 using SH. And used ecommerce extension to display new, topseller, toprated, popular products.. But all those products are displaying above slideshow.. How to move it below that container..

To display the products it is making a call to data.phtml. 
But i have tried renaming to someother name and calling all those files through admin->homepage. Before updating with SUPEE-6788 it was working fine.. But after installing magento 1.9.2.2 it is making call to data.phtml. How to call it through magento adminhome page

I have used below code to make a call instead of data.phtml

```
{{block type="homepage/topsell"  category_id="" template="ecommerceoffice/homepage/topsell.phtml"}}
{{block type="homepage/new"  category_id=0 template="ecommerceoffice/homepage/new.phtml"}}
{{block type="homepage/popular"  category_id=0 template="ecommerceoffice/homepage/popular.phtml"}}
{{block type="homepage/toprated"  category_id=0 template="ecommerceoffice/homepage/toprated.phtml"}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you whitelists the blocks ?

1. System > Permissions > Blocks
2. Add New Block
3. Block Name: cms/block
4. Is Allowed : Yes

after the update you need to white-list the blocks and clear cache

Comment: How are you calling the slider block ?

Comment: through cms home page.. It is same as madison island slider container

Comment: thank u i got it

Answer (score 3):

after upgrading with SUPEE-6788 we have to set permissions for all the blocks to call from homepage.

admin->permissions->blocks->and set permissions for all

[image]